# How do I match an element value and collect successive elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I get elements after `-p` or `--name` in this array

```
['-p', 'player', '1', '--name', 'player1', 'name']
```

Comment: Find the index, and then get the next value? `array.indexOf('-p')`

Comment: so if key is `-p`, you want result as  `[ 'player', '1', '--name', 'player1', 'name']` ?

Comment: key is `-p` i want the result doesnt have `--name` or other key after the elements that `-p` should have

Comment: so you mean if `-p` is key your result should be empty? & if `--name` is key, then your result should be` ['-p', 'player', '1']`? your question seems little bit confusing.

Comment: uh yes thats what i want

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of the element and splice the array at that index (+1 if you don't want that element):

```js
const arr = ['-p', 'player', '1', '--name', 'player1', 'name'];
var index = arr.indexOf("--name");

arr.slice(++index) // or just index if you also want "--name"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getNextElements(arr, str) {
    let res = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === str) {
            for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                res.push(arr[j])
            }
        }
    }
    return res
}

let arr = ['-p', 'player', '1', '--name', 'player1', 'name']
console.log(getNextElements(arr, '--name')) //Result: [ 'player1', 'name' ]
console.log(getNextElements(arr, '-p')) //Result: [ 'player', '1', '--name', 'player1', 'name' ]
```

Here, I have used simple For loops to come to the answer. The function takes an array and a string, after which we want elements.